# Escape from JS to HTML to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I need to have a `select` passed from JS to HTML.
The `select` should hold `option` from PHP.

So, first i have a **HTML** div where i will add the content from JS.

```
<div id="rows">
  <div class="thisRow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Next comes the **JS**

```
//Add row
$('#addRow').on('click', function(){

    //HTML Layout
    var htmlRow = '<div class="thisRow">\
                     <select>\
                       <option></option>\
                     </select>';

    //Append rows to document
    $('#rows').append(htmlRow);
});
```

Ok. So when i click the button with id #addRow my div with a select is passed into the HTMl.
Now i´d like to have more options in my select, and thoose come from Mysql.

If i try to pass PHP with HTML FROM JS i got problems with escaping charaters.

```
var htmlRow = '<div class="thisRow">\
                  <select>\
                      <option></option>\
                          <?php while(bla bla){ echo "<option>". $row['
```

<- Now i escaped back to JS. And i can´t use `"`because then i escape PHP.

I tried to escape special characters by `$row[\'bla\']`

The data to be shown as options i can fetch with php or ajax
But i cannot figure out how to include it...
So, how can i add options into my select from mysql?

**More**

This is a form. And you can add rows to it with a button. On each added row there are some text input and this select. The options for the select is fetched from Mysql. I can do it eigther with php on the HTML side.. or with Ajax on the Js side... But because i have this button to add rows.. i need to have my select added by js.

Comment: If this is a PHP page, why not just add the HTML rather than having it go through JavaScript? Do you want to fetch the select options via AJAX?

Comment: When a button `#addrow` is clicked, that is just when the select field will have its options? But the options is coming from your database, right?

Comment: this is not how websites work. your browser makes request. then your server side php app pareses the code and creates the html code and sends it as response to browser. Browser pareses the HTML code and executes javascript. no php here anymore...

Comment: This is a form. And you can add rows to it with a button. On each added row there are some text input and this select. The options for the select is fetched from Mysql. I can do it eigther with php on the HTML side.. or with Ajax on the Js side... But because i have this button to add rows.. i need to have my select added by js.

Comment: you can't "inject" php code using javascript, javascript works on the client while php works on the server so you can't add more PHP to a page you already have on your client (at least not this way). What you can do is to make your javascript do an ajax call to a php page that returns the already parsed HTML (that is, with the php stuff that gets computed by the server) and then put it inside your page

Comment: @valepu ok. That´s a thought. Make ajax call to php and mysql.. fetch data and create html with it.. pass it back to the js and the append it to html. I will try this.. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your select field to a file. Make sure that you name this field in an array `[]` format. Lets name it `select.php`:

```
<select name="field[]"> <!-- ARRAY FIELD -->
  <?php
    while($row = mysqli->fetch($result)){
      echo '<option value="'.$row["value"].'">'.$row["option"].'</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Then, you can fetch it using ajax.

```
$("#addRow").click(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    success: function(result){
      $("#rows).append(result);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that what you're trying to do can't possibly work, for future reference, you can use backticks for strings in [ES2015] JavaScript ([template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)):

```
var htmlRow = `<div class="thisRow">\
              <select>\
                  <option></option>\
                      <?php while(bla bla){ echo "<option>". $row[`
```

The very obvious problem here is: how is the PHP going to be evaluated? Cloning HTML fields - fine, no problem. but with this, you'll just be pasting strings that have the same characters as PHP code onto a webpage. The browser has no idea what to do with them, they are just strings of characters. You need to create an input element that submits to a PHP handler (likely via AJAX). Writing literal PHP code onto a webpage is never going to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have also facing this type of issue, so i have find solution for that.

when you dealing with js with in php code you need to first you html code convert in to js code. then you can use like below.

You can use http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/HTML_converter/ for that.

Example:

```
<?php
      $text  = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"; 
      $text .="document.writeln(\" <?php \"); \n"; 
      $text .="document.writeln(\" echo \\"\n\\"; \"); \n"; 
      $text .="document.writeln(\" ?> \");\n"; 
      $text .="</script>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to sanitize your data from mysql to html, try this tohtml() function

```
 echo "<option>". tohtml($row['bla']).'</option>';
function tohtml($str)
{
    return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);
}
```

Comment: tohtml() will escape all characters for HTML, making it safe to echo